# Java cant resize Array for fileinput

Tags: java, arrays

I tested the code by reducing one of the inputs to be 5 or below and it works fine but I want it to work with any number of inputs.
I want to change

```
RecordNewRun[] runners = new RecordNewRun[5]; // runner array
```

file input

```
10
Mary Bloggs
1996
3
2
Female
5
Marley Park
23.5
Marley Park
22.9
Marley Park
23.6
Marley Park
23.0
Marley Park
22.99
John Smith
1976
8
22
Male
1
St Anne's Park
33.5
Jane Mary O'Brien
2000
4
12
Female
2
shanganagh Park
26.5
shanganagh Park
26.7
Barry Ryan
1966
5
2
Male
3
Cabinteely Park
28.5
shanganagh Park
25.7
Cabinteely Park
27.9
Brian English
1953
11
20
Male
10
Cabinteely Park
18.5
Cabinteely Park
17.1
Cabinteely Park
16.8
Cabinteely Park
18.1
Cabinteely Park
18.6
Cabinteely Park
18.5
Cabinteely Park
18.1
Cabinteely Park
18.3
Cabinteely Park
18.1
Cabinteely Park
17.8
May English
1954
1
2
Female
0
Annie English
1955
10
12
Female
1
Cabinteely Park
47.8
Betty Green
1955
10
12
Female
2
Cabinteely Park
27.1
Cabinteely Park
```

to work for 10 or 20 or 50 runners but once I do I get a null output and the program prints, 1 runner, anything past 5 is too much and I'm missing out on what it could be and why I just cant change the array size to anything past 5,i know i can add some code to resize the array if it needs more space but i would much rather to find out why it wont let me go past 5

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ParkRunnerClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
            Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("file1.txt"));
            PrintStream printStreamOut = new PrintStream(new File("outputfile.txt"));
            String Sid = "A000000"; // barcode template
            //-----Park Runner ----//
            ParkRunner parkrunner1 = new ParkRunner(); // runner object
            RecordNewRun runnermm = new RecordNewRun(); //min max object    
            RecordNewRun[] runners = new RecordNewRun[5]; // runner array 
            Float[] times = new Float[runners.length]; // size of the array for calc avg min/mix
            float avg = 0;
            float sum = 0;
            int inputInt;
            int inputIntrun;
            int LapCount;
            String eatLine;  
try {    
            inputIntrun = fileInput.nextInt();
            printStreamOut.println("\nNumber of runners is:" + inputIntrun);
            printStreamOut.println(" ");   
            do 
      {

            parkrunner1.setRunnerId(Sid);
            printStreamOut.println("Runner barcode is: " + 
            parkrunner1.getRunnerId()); //runner barcode checked 

            eatLine = fileInput.nextLine();  
            parkrunner1.setName(fileInput.nextLine());
            printStreamOut.println("The name for runner is: " +                parkrunner1.getName());    

            parkrunner1.setAge(fileInput.nextInt());
            printStreamOut.println("runner age is:" + parkrunner1.getAge());  

            inputInt = fileInput.nextInt();
            printStreamOut.println("Month of birth is :" + inputInt);   
            inputInt = fileInput.nextInt();

            printStreamOut.println("Day of birth is:" + inputInt);    
            parkrunner1.setGender(fileInput.next().charAt(0));
            printStreamOut.println("runner gender M for male F for female:" + parkrunner1.getGender());  

            runnermm.setLaps(fileInput.nextInt());
            LapCount = runnermm.getLaps();
            runnermm.setLaps(LapCount);

            printStreamOut.println("Laps ran by runner is:" + runnermm.getLaps());   

            for(int i = 0; i < LapCount; i++)
                {  
            eatLine = fileInput.nextLine();  
            parkrunner1.setParkName(fileInput.nextLine());
            printStreamOut.println("Park  ran in is called: " + parkrunner1.getParkName());
            times[i] = fileInput.nextFloat();    
            sum = sum + times[i];    
            runnermm.setSum(sum);
            runnermm.setAvg(sum);    
                }   
            runnermm.getMinMax(times); // puts int array values into object runnermm (minmax) of RecordNewRun
            printStreamOut.println("\nThe sum of park runners time spend running is: " + runnermm.getSum());
            printStreamOut.println("\nThe average time of park runners time spent per lap is: " + runnermm.getAvg());
            printStreamOut.println(" ");    
            sum  = 0; // resets the array stored values in sum for each new runner  
        }while(runners.length < 10);  
        fileInput.close();    
}// end of try   
            catch (Exception  e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }    
}
```

this is the main file 
and  this is the RecordnewRun file

```
public class RecordNewRun

{
    //--------Data Declarations---------//
    private Float times;
    private Float sum;
    private Float avg;
    private int laps;  // new variable   
    //---Constructor that is being called to ParkRunnerClass--//
    public RecordNewRun(Float theSum, Float theAvg,int theLaps)
    {
        this.sum = theSum;
        this.avg = theAvg;
        this.laps = theLaps;
    }


    public RecordNewRun()
        {

        }

    //-------------------Setters and getters------------------------//
    //------sum set&get methods---------//
    public void  setSum(Float theSum)  
        {
            this.sum = theSum;
        }


        public double getSum()
        {
            return this.sum;
        }
//-----------------------------------//

    //-----runner laps--------//set + get
    public void setLaps(int theLaps)
    {
        this.laps = theLaps;
    }

    public int getLaps()
    {
        return this.laps;
    }


//------avg set&get methods---------//
    public void  setAvg(Float theAvg)
            {
                this.avg = (theAvg/this.laps);
            }

            public double getAvg()
            {
                return this.avg;
            }

     public void getMinMax(Float [] times)
    {
        // getmethod for getting max value
        Float max = getMax(times);   
        //getmethod for getting min value
        Float min = getMin(times);  
      }

      //getmethod for max val
      public  Float getMax(Float[] times)
      {
        Float maxVal = times[0];    
        for(int i = 1;i < times.length;i++)
            {
          if(times[i] > maxVal)
                {
             maxVal = times[i];
                }
            }
        return maxVal;  
      }

      //getmethod for min val
      public  Float getMin(Float[] times)
      {
        Float minVal = times[0];
        for(int i = 1;i < times.length;i++)
            {
          if(times[i] < minVal)
                {
            minVal = times[i];
                }
            }
        return minVal;    
      }


}//closes definition of class RecordNewRunner
```

There is an aditional file called parkrunner but its only for some set and get methods ill add it at the bottom but i doubt its whats causing the issue

```
public class ParkRunner
{
    //--------Data Declarations---------
    private String name; // stayed the same
    private String RunnerId; //barcode id // studentid
    private String parkname; // array variable
    private char gender; //grade = gender
    private int age; // new variable
    private float time; // array
    private int b = 0;    
    //------------------------------------------------------//
    //Setter methods are used to set values for class data
    //Getter methos are used  to get values for class data
    //-----------------------------------------------------// 
    //---Constructor that is being called to ParkRunnerClass--//
    public ParkRunner(String theId, String theName, float theTime,char theGender,int theAge,String theParkName)   
    {   
    this.parkname = theParkName;
    this.age = theAge;
    this.RunnerId = theId;
    this.name = theName;
    this.time = theTime;
    this.gender = theGender;    
    }

    //--- setting empty parameters---
    public ParkRunner()
    {     }

    //-----park name --------//set + get
    public void setParkName(String theParkName)
    {
        this.parkname = theParkName;
    }

    public String getParkName()
    {
        return this.parkname;
    }

    //-----runner age--------// set + get
    public void setAge(int theAge) 
    {
        this.age = 2018 - theAge;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
    //-----runner gender -------- set + get
    public void setGender(char theGender)
    {
        this.gender = theGender;
    }

    public char getGender()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }

    //-----RunnerId -------- set + get
    public void setRunnerId(String theId)
    {
        b = b + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                        this.RunnerId = theId + b;
            }
    }

    public String getRunnerId()
    {
        return this.RunnerId;
    }

    //-----runner time --------//set + get
    public void  setTime(float theTime)
    {
        this.time = theTime;
    }

    public float getTime()
    {
    return this.time;
    }

    //----Runner name ------//set + get
    public void setName(String theName)

    {
        this.name = theName;
    }

    public  String getName()

    {
        return this.name;
    }





} //closes definition of class Runner
```

Comment: Don't use arrays, use the [Java collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use arrays when the length is unknown.
I don't know about others but I prefer using [ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

It's a lot more helpful. Here's a sample:

```
import java.util.*;  
    public class ListExample{  
        public static void main(String args[]){  
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
        al.add("Amit");  
        al.add("Vijay");  
        al.add("Kumar");  
        al.add(1,"Sachin");  
        System.out.println("Element at 2nd position: "+al.get(2));  
        for(String s:al){  
            System.out.println(s);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: its a bit late but i wanted to add the issue was my input file had bad input once i fixed that my code worked fine